# After changing WooCommerce mail templates, translation feature stops working. Why?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce in Japanese and have just modified mail template 'customer-processing-order.php' to display the customer's full name instead of his/her first name.

```
//before
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>

//after 
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ) ); ?></p>
```

This works fine, but the sentence below this is not translated to Japanese any more.

```
//This sentence is not translated to Japanese
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Just to let you know — we\'ve received your order #%s, and it is now being processed:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?></p>
```

I'm keeping this part intact and before making any changes, this part was translated to Japanese without problem.

Other Sentences following this are still translated into Japanese.
I have problem with just this sentence "Just to let you know — we've received your order #%s, and it is now being processed:"

I'd like to know why and the solution for this.

> Additional info: 
> I modified mail template in admin screen going to:
> WooCommerce > Settings > Emails > Processing order > Manage  Then I
> clicked 'Copy file to theme' button, then modified on edit screen.
>
> WordPress Version 5.5  WooCommerce Version 4.4.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked in WooCommerce Status > Templates
*Overrides* (section), if your overridden templates are up to date. Also what are you using for translation? Did you Update WooCommerce in between?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I've just added additional infomation to my question.
As for translation, it's supposed to be used WooCommerce's original translation file in /wp/wp-content/languages/plugins/woocommerce-ja.mo and woocommerce-ja.po
About the status, it displays template '/themename/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php' as overrided file.